# NestJS - Testing @Inject('Value') Dependency

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

Trying to test a class that uses @Inject() to inject its dependencies.

### users.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, HttpCode, Body, Post, Inject, Get, Param } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { UploadPhoto } from './usecase/upload-photo.usecase';
import { UploadPhotoReqDto } from './dto/upload-photo.req.dto';
import { Document } from 'dynamoose/dist/Document';
import { DynamooseModel } from '../dynamoose/dynamoose-model.interface';
import { InjectModel } from '../dynamoose/common/dynamoose.decorator';

@ApiTags('Users')
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
    constructor(
        private readonly uploadPhoto: UploadPhoto,
        @Inject('UserModel') private readonly UserModel: DynamooseModel<Document>
    ) {}

    @Post('/profile/upload_photo')
    @HttpCode(200)
    async postUploadPhoto(@Body() requestBody: UploadPhotoReqDto): Promise<string> {
        const { mime, image } = requestBody;
        const image_url = await this.uploadPhoto.start({ mime, image });
        return image_url;
    }
}
```

This is my test class.

### users.controller.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { UploadPhoto } from './usecase/upload-photo.usecase';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';

const BaseUseCaseMock = {
    start: () => {
        console.log('Starting BaseUseCaseMock');
    },
};

describe('UsersController', () => {
    let controller: UsersController;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            controllers: [UsersController],
            providers: [
                UploadPhoto,
                {
                    provide: 'UserModel',
                    useValue: {},
                },
            ],
        })
            .overrideProvider(UploadPhoto)
            .useValue(BaseUseCaseMock)
            .compile();

        controller = module.get<UsersController>(UsersController);
    });

    it('Should_BeDefined', () => {
        expect(controller).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

[image]

All I'm checking for the time being is if the UsersController got instantiated properly. Is this the correct use for the NestJS custom providers?

Any ideas on why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing on Discord, the issue was in the `users.service.spec.ts` file having the same setup without the mocked dependencies. The above test is actually fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was a silly mistake on my part. I'll leave the question up in case someone runs into something similar or makes the same error.